# Criteria API creates the HQR query that fails with doubled brace

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

The line of Criteria API

```
c.select(cb.count(concatSubQuery.getSelection()));
```

caused the below error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 14 [select count((select generatedAlias0.name from com.openpayment.impl.entity.RegistryGroupEntity as generatedAlias1 where generatedAlias1.id=generatedAlias2.id)) from com.openpayment.impl.entity.RegistryGroupEntity as generatedAlias2 left join generatedAlias2.services as generatedAlias0 order by generatedAlias2.name desc
```

The removing of both select and getSelection() doesn't eliminate the problem

```
c.select(cb.count(concatSubQuery));
```

The full method is:

CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery c = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
Root registryGroup = c.from(RegistryGroupEntity.class);

```
    Join<RegistryGroupEntity, ServiceEntity> serviceJoin = registryGroup.join(RegistryGroupEntity_.services, JoinType.LEFT);
    //здесь мы хотим получить все возможные услуги для поиска в фильре

    Subquery<String> concatSubQuery = c.subquery(String.class);
    Root<RegistryGroupEntity> countSubQueryRoot = concatSubQuery.from(RegistryGroupEntity.class);
    concatSubQuery.select(serviceJoin.get(ServiceEntity_.name))
            .where(cb.equal(countSubQueryRoot.get(RegistryGroupEntity_.id),
                    registryGroup.get(RegistryGroupEntity_.id)));

    c.select(cb.count(concatSubQuery));
    c.orderBy(cb.desc(registryGroup.get(RegistryGroupEntity_.name)));

    List<Predicate> criteria = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, Object> paramValues = new HashMap<>();
    if (name != null) {
        ParameterExpression<String> p = cb.parameter(String.class, "name");
        criteria.add(cb.like(registryGroup.get(RegistryGroupEntity_.name), p));
        paramValues.put("name", name);
    }
    if (criteria.size() == 1) {
        c.where(criteria.get(0));
    } else if (criteria.size() > 0) {
        c.where(cb.and(criteria.toArray(new Predicate[0])));
    }

    TypedQuery<Long> q = entityManager.createQuery(c);

    for (String paramName : paramValues.keySet()) {
        q.setParameter(paramName, paramValues.get(paramName));
    }

    return q.getSingleResult();
```

entities are:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "registry_groups")
public class RegistryGroupEntity {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="registry_groups_gen", sequenceName="registry_groups_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator="registry_groups_gen")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "registryGroup")
    private Collection<ServiceEntity> services;
//setters-getters ommited
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "services")
public class ServiceEntity {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="service_gen", sequenceName="services_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator="service_gen")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "registry_group_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer registryGroupId;

}
```